# Better way to limit the number of form validation attempts in my MVC controller and redirect to another action when limit is reached?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am fairly new to MVC and am looking for some much needed guidance.

The goal is to determine when a user is banging their head against a wall for any given action and redirect them to a different page with contact information for our "Help Desk".

I have code that is functional but ugly and not very re-usable.  (Validation is handled in a ViewModel):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyForm(MyForm model)
    {....

        if (ModelState.IsValid){..... return RedirectToAction("Success")}

        var attempts = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Attempts"]);            
        if (attempts >= 3)
        {
            TempData["LocalMessages"] = new Message
            {
                Class = "Alert",
                Text =
                    "It looks like you are having trouble ...Please Contact...."
            };
            return RedirectToAction("HelpDesk");
        }
        attempts += 1;
        TempData["Attempts"] = attempts;
        return View(model);
```

An ideal solution would be to leverage something like an Action Filter so I could do the following for any given action:

```
    [HttpPost, MaximumAttemptBeforeRedirect(4, "HelpDesk")]
    public ActionResult MyForm(MyForm model)
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I was looking for (I made use of Brian Wilson's Stateful Storage class from his blog post http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2011/02/advanced-aspnet-mvc-3-presentation.html):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class MaximumAttemptBeforeRedirectAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{        
    readonly IStatefulStorage _storage = StatefulStorage.PerSession;        
    private readonly int _maxAttempt;
    private readonly RedirectToRouteResult _newRoute;
    private string _keyName;
    public MaximumAttemptBeforeRedirectAttribute(int attempts, string controller, string action)
    {
        _maxAttempt = attempts;
        var rvDic = new RouteValueDictionary {{"action", action}, {"controller", controller}};
        _newRoute = new RedirectToRouteResult(rvDic);

    }

    Attempts GetCount(string name)
    {
        return _storage.GetOrAdd(name, () => new Attempts());
    }        

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        _keyName = string.Format("{0}{1}Attempts",
                      filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"],
                      filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
                     );

        var errCount = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Values.Where(v => v.Errors.Count != 0).Count();
        if (errCount > 0) //If errors, increment attempt count by 1
        {
            GetCount(_keyName).Increment();
        }
        else //If no errors, reset attempt count.
        {
            GetCount(_keyName).Reset();
        }


        if (GetCount(_keyName).Number < _maxAttempt) return; //user is within allowed threshold for validation attempts so stop here.

        //Do we give the user the opportunity to navigate back to the page and try again in durring life of current session?
        GetCount(_keyName).Reset(); //user can now go back to the page again and try another x times.

        var route = string.Format("{0}/{1}", filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"],
                                  filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]);

        Logger.WarnFormat("Max Attempts were reached for {0}/{1}", filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"], filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]);                        
        filterContext.Controller.TempData["LocalMessages"] = new Message
                                                    {
                                                        Class = "Alert", 
                                                        Text = "You have exceeded the allowed number of attempts for " + route
                                                    };
        filterContext.Result = _newRoute;
    }

}
```

This allows me to add the following to my ActionResult or to my Controller:

```
[HttpPost, MaximumAttemptBeforeRedirect(4, "MyController", "SomeAction")]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could include the number of attempts as a property of your view model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyForm(MyForm model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }

    ModelState.Remove("Attempts");
    model.Attempts++;
    if (model.Attempts >= 3)
    {
        TempData["LocalMessages"] = new Message
        {
            Class = "Alert",
            Text = "It looks like you are having trouble ...Please Contact...."
        };
        return RedirectToAction("HelpDesk");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

and include the number of attempts as a hidden field in the form:

```
<%= Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Attempts) %>
```

Comment: I tried that.  Perhaps I'm doing something wrong but updating the model doesn't update the ModelState.  The hidden field never receives the incremented value.

Comment: @user210422, it's the `ModelState.Remove("Attempts")` instruction that is supposed to do this.

Comment: However....  Even with the removal of the TempData call, my code still isn't as re-usable as I would like.  I'm wondering if something in the area of an Action Filter would work...